# Div's with display: inline-block; have strange top margin

Tags: html, css

I have created two div's, both with `display: inline-block`. As long as both div's contain the same amount of text, the vertical alignment is fine. But if I add more text to the first div, the second one gets a strange top margin. The more text I add, the higher the top margin of the second div gets.

You can check the problem out in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krcLh9nu/) (you'll probably have to watch the full-screen result to see what I'm talking about.

Could anybody please help me? I've looked on Stackoverflow, but I can't find an answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align: top;` to the `<div class="box">`

Comment: Didn't know it was that easy, thanks!